# Refresh the activity when the language change item is triggered

Tags: android, multilingual

My application need to support multi language. I want to change the application language from all activities of the app. So I am using Base_Activity and placing the spinner in the action bar. The problem is to change the language here. When I trigger some item in spinner to change the language, it does not change. But after triggered the item and go to next activity it is changed there. I am trying to refresh page after triggering each time to get the triggered language. How can I refresh the page with the another lanuage when the language item in spinner is selected. My code seems like this;

```
public class Base_Activity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.getItem(0).getActionView()
            .findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.languages, R.layout.spinner_row);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        // private String currentLanguage;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            // currentLanguage = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Locale locale = null;
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                locale = new Locale("en_US");
                break;
            case 1:
                locale = new Locale("fi");
                break;
            case 2:
                locale = new Locale("fr");
                break;
            case 3:
                locale = new Locale("de");
                break;
            case 4:
                locale = new Locale("sk");

                break;
            case 5:
                locale = new Locale("pl");
                break;

            default:
                locale = new Locale("en_US");
                break;
            }
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            startActivity();
        }

        private void startActivity() {
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            Log.i("DEBUG", "GATEWAY");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

        }

    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale localeNew = new Locale(locale); 
Locale.setDefault(localeNew);

Configuration configNew = new Configuration();
configNew.locale = localeNew;

getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configNew, null);
```

Comment: what is the difference in my code and you provided to me. I think it might work as same that itis working.